# User selects item from drop down box, clicks button, and the selected item populates the last row of a table

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Microsoft word, I have a 3x3 table, a button, and a drop down list.

When I press the button, I want the last row of the first column to be filled with the selected drop down list item. Then, add a row to the table below it.

Currently, I can't even fill values into the table.

`ActiveDocument.Tables(15).Rows.Last.Cells.Value = "Hello"` returns an error. What can I do?

I managed to select the last row. `ActiveDocument.Tables(15).Rows.Last.Select`

Now, I need to copy the current value from the drop down list. How do I do that?

Comment: Without seeing your entire document it is difficult to see where you are stuck. Nonetheless, the code to set text to a table cell should be something like `ActiveDocument.Tables(15).Rows.Last.Cells(2).Range.Text = "Hello"` (if that helps you any further)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. It inserts the text after any existing text:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PopulateTable()

    With ActiveDocument

        .Tables(1).Rows.Last.Cells(1).Range.InsertAfter .FormFields("DropDown1").Result

    End With

End Sub
```

If you know the specific cell location you could also use:

```
.Tables(1).Cell(3, 1).Range.InsertAfter .FormFields("DropDown1").Result
```

References:

1) [table-cell-method-word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/table-cell-method-word)

2) [dropdown-object-word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/dropdown-object-word)

You can loop so see which form fields are present in the `Activedocument` and get their names as follows:

```
Sub GetNames()

Dim myField As FormField

For Each myField In ActiveDocument.FormFields

    Debug.Print myField.Name

Next myField

End Sub
```

If you double click on the drop down form control it will open a window where you can view the `Bookmark` name i.e. the current name for the drop down object.

You can also associate a macro via this route (so could remove need for a button potentially)

[image: Dropdown]

Legacy form control:

[image: Legacy form control Drop down]

Comment: Is there a way to see what my dropdown list object is currently called? It might not be "DropDown1". Sorry I am unfamiliar with ms word objects

Comment: I see.. Is there any way of knowing what my drop down list is called by clicking on it? There are hundreds of FormFields in this document from my Debug.Print

Comment: Nothing happens when I double click it. I created the drop down list from: Developer tab -> Controls -> Drop Down List Content Control. Am I on the right path?

Comment: I used the legacy forms controls to insert the control. See edit.