# Pulling value from drop down list, trouble due to form protection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a button, a legacy drop down form, and a table.

When I press my button, VBA code pulls the currently selected item from my legacy drop down form, and inserts it into my table.

```
With ActiveDocument

    .Tables(15).Rows.Last.Cells(1).Range.InsertAfter .FormFields("DropDown2").Result

End With
```

However, the drop down list does not "drop down" when I am in non-protected mode. I need users to be able to select from the drop down form.

So, I changed to protected-mode to allow the drop down list to function normally. However, when I run the macro in protected mode, I receive this error:

```
This method or property is not available because the object refers to a protected area of a document.
```

What can I do? Is my approach totally wrong, or is there a fix for this?

This is a follow up to [User selects item from drop down box, clicks button, and the selected item populates the last row of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48438385/user-selects-item-from-drop-down-box-clicks-button-and-the-selected-item-popul/48439045?noredirect=1#comment83873119_48439045)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should check if the document is protected (which it sounds like it will be). Then *temporarily* disable the protection, make your changes, the re-enable protection.

```
With ActiveDocument
    If .ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then .Unprotect
    .Tables(15).Rows.Last.Cells(1).Range.InsertAfter .FormFields("DropDown2").Result
    .Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields
End With
```

So go ahead and keep your document protected for your drop down. This code will take care of the rest.

Comment: If I want to add `ActiveDocument.Tables(15).Rows.Add` at the end of it, so that I can add a row to my table after `.InsertAfter`, where should I add it in? Does it need to be within the With condition?